# php replace empty record in a row with a letter

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I'm trying to replace an empty record in a row with "N" letter... Im pulling records from mysql database... this is my code

```
 <?php

include_once 'dbconnect1.php';

$sql=$dbcon->query("SELECT id, Data, sensor1, sensor2, sensor3, sensor4, 
sensor5, sensor6  FROM sensors ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");  

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){ 

echo($row["Data"]."<br>");
echo($row["sensor1"]."<br>");
echo($row["sensor2"]."<br>");
echo($row["sensor3"]."<br>");
echo($row["sensor4"]."<br>");
echo($row["sensor5"]."<br>");
echo($row["sensor6"]."<br>");
}    
mysqli_close($dbcon);

?>
```

This is my print:

```
2018-02-08 00:12:22
20
32

0
0
0
```

I want after number 32 instead of empty space to print letter "N"

Comment: try `echo empty($row["sensor3"]) ? "N" : $row["sensor3"];`

Comment: `if(condition == ""){...}` or `empty()`. Yet, remember that NULL !=  empty, should this be the case.

Comment: you've too many unclosed questions, IMHO.

Comment: This schema violates the 
[Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of 
[database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). That should be a one-to-many relationship between the sample and the sensors.

Comment: it can be any sensor depends of records in database... I want generally if there is any empty record in database to be printed like letter "N"... not just sensor3

Comment: `echo $row['sensor']?: 'N';`

Comment: ok this works for empty record echo NULL != empty($row["sensor3"]) ? "N"."<br>" : $row["sensor3"]."<br>"; but I want "0" to print "0" ... with this code "0" also prints "N"

Comment: You need to get into the habit of marking answers as correct, else people will probably start being less willing to help you. To do this, just click the little checkmark to the left of the answer that helped you the most on all of your questions. Links to your other questions can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5257429/tanjamaya).

Answer (score 1):

A conditional should do the trick, the below will default to "N" if Data is empty, otherwise it will echo Data.

```
echo((empty($row["Data"]) ? "N" : $row["Data"])."<br>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this - I'm not a big fan of this way but it should work. I haven't tested it.

```
$sql=$dbcon->query("SELECT id, Data, sensor1, sensor2, sensor3, sensor4, 
sensor5, sensor6  FROM sensors ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");  

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){ 

 echo($row["Data"]."<br>");
 echo($row['sensor1']?: 'N'. "<br>");
 echo($row['sensor2']?: 'N'. "<br>");
 echo($row['sensor3']?: 'N'. "<br>");
 echo($row['sensor4']?: 'N'. "<br>");
 echo($row['sensor5']?: 'N'. "<br>");
 echo($row['sensor6']?: 'N'. "<br>");

}
```

Comment: as I seyed before I need only empty records to be printed as "N" letter, all other numbers (0, 1, 2, 3...   ) to be printer as they are... with this code number "0" is printed as "N" as well... I need to be "0" as "0"

Answer (score 0):

MySQL empty values are null, and in both above responses the evaluation of the expression will be treated as boolean, so you need to use $val==null in your expression instead of only checking the value.

Comment: sorry about my comments can someone write the all code... I'm not professional in php coding

Comment: $row['sensor1']! ==null? $row['sensor1'] : 'N'